# CGPA Calc Python

Tags: python, linux, calculator

Help me please. im tryning to do a CGPA calculator. but someonething just goes wrong and i couldn't find the answer :'( i get this error message saying:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      file "cgpa.py", line 60 in 7
           count_sem, total_gpa, credit = input_user().
      file "cgpa.py", line 53, in input_user
           total_gpa=total_gpa + gpa
 unboudndlocalerror:local variable "gpa" reference before assignment
```

is there something wrong with my coding or the format somehow? i expect it to display funcion cgpa when the user press 1 for the menu. and the looping should end when the user enter finish then goes to the menu.

```
def menu(): 

 print "\n\n----CGPA MENU----\nChoose the option below:\n" 
 print "Enter 1 - Total CGPA"   print "Enter 2 - Total semester"  
 print "Enter 3 - Target Next GPA (if CGPA < 3.0)"
 print "Enter 4 - EXIT "    user_menu = raw_input ("Option: ")
    return user_menu      

def cgpa(a,b):
     average = a/b      

     return average

def input_user(): 
     while True:
            count_sem = 0
            total_gpa = 0
            credit = 0

            print "\n~To STOP enter finish~"

            user1 = raw_input ("Enter GPA: ") 
            if user1 == "finish":           break
            try:
                    gpa = float (user1) 
            except:
                    print "Invalid number"
                    continue

            user2 = raw_input ("Semester: ")
            try:
                    sem = int(user2)
            except:
                    print "Invalid number"
                    continue        

            user3 = raw_input ("Enter total credit hour: ")
            try: 
                    hour =    int(user3)
            except:
                    print "Invalid number"
                    continue

            count_sem = count_sem + 1
            total_gpa = total_gpa + gpa
            credit =    credit + hour

        return count_sem, total_gpa, credit     

 while True:    
             count_sem, total_gpa, credit = input_user ()   
             user_menu = menu ()

             if user_menu == 1:
                     cgpa2 = cgpa (total_gpa,count_sem) 
                     print "Total CGPA: %.2f" % cgpa2

            elif user_menu == 2: 
                    print "22222@"
             print "DONE"
```

Comment: This is Homework?

Comment: no. im trying to improve my python language. but im just a beginner. do help me? @prakharsingh95

Comment: i get this message ... Traceback (most recent call last): file "cgpa.py", line 60 in 7. count_sem, total_gpa, credit = input_user(). file "cgpa.py", line 53, in input_user. total_gpa=total_gpa + gpa. unboud=ndlocalerror:local variable "gpa" reference before assignment

Comment: done wat u guys told me @Makoto @/Rad Lexus